# How to convert a web service from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl

I have 2 seperate web services that currently use HTTP. (C#)

1 is a Soap web service (asmx)

1 is a WebAPI restful service.

Is there anything particular that I will need to do code wise to make both of these web services SSL only?

Would all of the configuration to SSL take part on the server?

Comment: How are your services hosted?  IIS?

Comment: Right now locally on my dev machine.  The network admin said they will have to be deployed using SSL but he didn't know how.  (It will be IIS 8 I believe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the environment.

First you need to purchase a certificate. If you search for Comodo cert, you'll find many resellers for them including folks like namecheap.com

Then, you'll have to see how to install. If using Azure or Google Cloud, etc, they usually install on a separate Load Balancer. In general, large systems usually terminate the SSL link well before hitting any application servers, but for your setup may be easiest to just leverage IIS for now.

If it's your own IIS setup, take a look at DigiCert's instructions. While their certs are very expensive, they do have good documentation/tools. https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm

There are some tools like Let's Encrypt that try to make SSL Cert issuance easier, but for now it's sometimes more complicated to set up. I usually like just buying a wildcard cert so you can easily have subdomains like blog.example.com, etc.